# Usage of 'the' in this statement

Tags: meaning, definite-articles

If  a person said:

> I believe in the teachings of Jesus Christ.

Would the above statement, without any additional context than that provided, mean:

(1a) The Person believes in the **complete** set of JC's teachings;

OR

(2a) The Person believes in an **unspecified subset** of the set of JC's teachings?

OR

(3a) Either interpretation is justifiable, however further context is **necessary** to justify one over the other.

[**EDIT** The original purpose of the question was to identify how 'the' functions in the sentence, so I'll provide a hopefully less non-contested example that will prevent anyone getting bogged down in the ambiguities brought about by the bible:
Instead, consider the statements:

> I have read the works of Joseph Conrad.

AND

> I have read Joseph Conrad's works

Does the former statement mean:

(1b) The Person has read **all** of Joseph Conrad's works

OR

(2b) The Person has read an **unspecified subset** of Joseph Conrad's works

OR

(3b) Further context is **necessary** to justify one over the other.

Finally, are both statements meaningfully identical? If not, what meaning would the second statement have?

Comment: Would the person who marked this question down care to explain why? It is a reasonable question that touches nicely on ambiguity, meaning and logic within the usage of English. Unexplained markdown may discourage new contributors to the site. Welcome to the site, TomDot.

Comment: This is impossible to answer definitively  (though not deserving of a downvote). "I believe that Blondin could push someone in a wheelbarrow on a tightrope over Niagara Falls" seems a pretty clear declaration of faith, but the reaction to "OK, monsieur, hop in!" will demonstrate its truth value. And subsequent events whether or not the trust was misplaced. // So even 'I believe ...' involves complex psycholinguistics. Probably, no person uttering "I believe in the teachings of Jesus Christ" is being utterly realistic/truthful (James 2:26; Matt 26:31; some versions have 'scandalised', ...

Comment: 'offended' rather than 'fall away' / 'stumble'). Of course, Peter didn't consider that he _could_ reject Jesus (and his complete teachings / lifestyle / calling). // That said, even "I like desserts" would be used (outside a logistics class) to mean "There are few desserts I'd refuse." Pragmatics and precisionist usage often vary significantly. // Globally, does any human fully understand Jesus's teachings? If not, how can they be sure they 'believe' them fully? Paul seems to have made more of a mark than many of us present-day Christians. Orthopraxy and orthodoxy go hand-in-hand.

Comment: There is ambiguity in the bible (KJV is the one I use) in the statement 'the faith of Jesus Christ' where sometimes it is difficult to say if the particular apostle is referring to Jesus Christ's own faith in his Father, God, or if the apostle means 'the gospel (that is to say the whole teaching) of Jesus Christ', or if the apostle is referring to the faith of a particular person _in_ Jesus Christ. The question is quite valid in scriptural terms. [The down-votes could, possibly, be due to the use of Jesus Christ's initials, rather than his proper name.]

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, it may be impossible to answer definitely whether (1) or (2) is correct, but that **is** precisely what (3) says. The question which of the three options offered by the OP is the correct one can thus be answered definitely.

Comment: What you’re asking is whether, without any additional context, the  statements “I believe in the teachings of ... “ and “I believe in some of the teachings of ...” mean exactly the same thing and are interchangeable with no change in meaning.

Comment: @jsw2 Not until you've agreed on a definition of 'believe' [in a teaching]. John 14:12, NIV [[BibleGateway](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2014:12-14&version=NIV)]: 'Very truly I tell you, whoever believes in me will do the works I have been doing, and they will do even greater things than these, because I am going to the Father.' Perhaps the first question is 'If a person says: "I believe in the teachings of Jesus Christ" are they telling the truth?'

Comment: Generally option (3).  Context may give better specificity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP has presented the question as a multiple-choice one, but this answer will combine the elements of all three of the options that the question offers.

If somebody claims to have read 'the works of Joseph Conrad', and it then turns out that there is, in fact, one not-well-known story that he hasn't read, we won't accuse him of lying. So, clearly, we do not take his claim to amount to (1b). On the other hand, if it turns out that he has read only a couple of Conrad's novels, we would feel that it was misleading of him to say that he has read 'the works of Joseph Conrad' (assuming, as the OP does, that the context was not specifically about these novels). So we do not interpret the claim as (2b) either, but as something between (1b) and (2b). The claim that one has read 'the works of Joseph Conrad' is the claim that one has read **enough** of them to be well acquainted with the style and themes that run through his works. What counts as 'enough' here may partially depend on the context, so this answer has elements of (3b) as well.

Answer (score -1):

I understand why there appears to be ambiguity but if there is no context the answer is clear. There are many things that are taught; there are therefore many possible subsets of taught things. Use of the definite article implies that we are reading about one thing. That being the case, it cannot refer to an undefined subset chosen from many.

Therefore, without any context, the statement applies to the complete set of all that JC taught.

Comment: Although the argument is logical, there is some precedent for using this form (‘the’ *<thing>*) to refer to a weaker subscription - they might subscribe to just a ‘general sense’ of the whole.

Answer (score -1):

"the teachings" is plural, and since no specific subset is mentioned it must be assumed to refer to the entire body of teachings.

There is some room for ambiguity only because the object refers to a controversial individual. The existence of apocryphal and contested documents makes "the teachings" an unclear concept. This is a philosophical issue, not a linguistic one. Linguistically, the sentence is unambiguous and correct.

Comment: So if perhaps the statement was supplanted by: "I believe in the philosophy of Plato" would this then be assumed to refer to the totality of Plato's philosophies, assuming 'his philosophy' is not as equivocal as JC's teachings?

Comment: @TomDotCom, Plato's philosophy has, in fact, been interpreted in quite a few different ways, but even if it hadn't been, somebody's saying that he believes in it would exhibit the same ambiguity as your original example: it could mean that the person accepts all the details of his theory (unlikely these days, but possible) or that he regards that theory as, generally, on the right track, even if it is wrong in the specifics. (Philosophers usually avoid saying they 'believe in' a particular theory, but that does not affect the point.)

Comment: You say that 'since no specific subset is mentioned it must be assumed to refer to the entire body of teachings'. Why must it be assumed?

Comment: @jsw29 Pete and I argue the same. If “I saw the club members”, the definite article means that I must be referring to them all, not just to the men, the women, the ones with blue eyes, the office holders, the honorary members, or any other subset. I find it inexplicable that someone has marked us both down on a simple matter of grammar and logic without saying why.  I can only assume some religious clouding of their reasoning.